# How to filter a sub list which is part of another list in C#

Tags: c#

I want to filter the list which is already part of another list.

Consider,

Class MainClass

```
  properties

      String Name

      String MainAddress

      List<SubClass> ExtraInfo
```

Class SubClass

```
  properties

      String Address

      String City

      String PhoneNo
```

Now i have 10 items in my List and each item in List has 2 ExtraInfo items this is List items.

Now i want to filter List items with Condition City == "New York".

So, all 10 items in the main list (List) should have the ExtraInfo (List) items based on the filter condition.

I mean i just want to filter the Sub list not the main list.

Thanks in Advance!

Sample Data
     Name      MainAddress       ExtraInfo
                                    Address        City        Phone No
1.  Vimal      Bangalore            North Street   New York    654564646 --->Sub item 1
                                    North Street   California  464654565 --->Sub item 2

1. Hareesh      Chennai            North Street   Washington  546466466 --->Sub item 1
                                   Tower B        New York    464645465 --->Sub item 2

After Filter (Condition City == "New York"), I should get the output in the main list like

```
 Name      MainAddress       ExtraInfo
                                Address        City        Phone No
```

1.  Vimal      Bangalore            North Street   New York    654564646 --->Sub item 1

1. Hareesh      Chennai            Tower B        New York    464645465 --->Sub item 1

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to filter each of the sublists:

```
List<MainClass> mainList = ...
foreach(MainClass main in mainList)
{
    ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(main.ExtraInfo);
    view.Filter = ExtraInfoFilter;
}

bool ExtraInfoFilter(object obj)
{
    ExtraInfo item = (ExtraInfo)obj;

    return item.City == "New York";
}
```

Comment: Hi I want to filter like this. List<MainClass> mainList = ... 
mainList.ForEach(m => m.ExtraInfo.RemoveAll(subClass => subClass.City != "New York")); But this removes items from sublist instead i just want to filter it.

Comment: I don't understand your comment... the code you mention is the one from Ani's answer, not mine. My code doesn't remove anything, it only filters the items that are displayed in a WPF list

Answer (score 1):

I might not have understood the question correctly, but:

```
List<MainClass> mainList = ...
mainList.ForEach(m => m.ExtraInfo.RemoveAll(subClass => subClass.City != "New York"));
```

This will modify each item in `mainList` in place, by removing all items from its list-member`ExtraInfo`(in place) for which each item in the list (of type`SubClass`) does not have "New York" as its`City`. Is that what you want?

If you simply want all of the 'embedded'`ExtraInfo`items that match the filter no matter which MainClass's list they belong to, you could do this:

```
var filteredSubClasses = mainList.SelectMany(m => m.ExtraInfo)
                                 .Where(subClass => subClass.City == "New York");
```

EDIT: Based on the OP's comment:
This is a bit ugly, but should be what you need:

```
var filteredList = mainList.Select(m => new MainClass
                            { 
                               Name = m.Name;
                               MainAddress = m.MainAddress;
                               ExtraInfo = m.ExtraInfo
                                            .Where(subClass => subClass.City == "New York")
                                            .ToList()
                            })
                          .ToList();
```

IMO, it would be easier if MainClass supplied a copy-constructor or clone-method to remove the need to copy all the properties over one by one. This is a bit brittle - it will break  if you add a new property to `MainClass`.

Comment: Hi Ani, I want all the main list items with the filtered items in ExtraInfo list. This is something similar to your first statement but instead of removing all the remaining items, I want just to do filter

Comment: @ksvimal Could you give us a sample input and sample output? That would really help.

Comment: I have updated my initial post with Sample data and output. Please let me know if it is not clear.

Comment: @ksvimal: Are there any issues with the edited code I posted?

Comment: Actually in my actual scenario i do access both Main Class and Subclass through interface say I_mainClass and I_subclass and i may not able to access the Main class directly in my BL. So just wondering how to do it.